# Can I get the number of integer partitions into k parts using the stars and bars technique?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I was learning integer partition of a number n into k parts.
My initial solution was $\frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{k}$ and later found out the actual formula is $p(n,k)=p(n-k,k) + p(n-1,k-1)$
Is my solution correct? $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ is from the stars and bars problem - the number of k-tuples of positive integers whose sum is n and I divide by k because we are counting some more than we should. Here is an example.
$p(5,3)=2$
$x_1+x_2+x_3=5$ where $x\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$
$\binom{5-1}{3-1}=6$ because we count 1+1+3,1+3+1,3+1+1 as three different and same as 2+2+1,2+1+2,1+2+2 
So that's why I divide by k, which brings us to $\frac{6}{3}=2=p(5,3)$
Of course this is only one example and not a proof and that's why I want to hear your opinion if it's a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot.  The number of orders depends on how many of the pieces are equal.  For example, $10=1+2+3+4$ is counted $4!=24$ times.  Your counts of $k$ times applies when one part is distinct but all the rest are equal.  Counting partitions is harder than counting combinations for this reason.  The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) shows how to count them.

Answer (score 0):

Nah I am wrong. $p(7,3)=4$ and $mySolution(7,3)=5$ and many more different results when I coded my problem in Java, so the answer is no, my solution is not the solution to the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).